# What are the tradeoffs between a single HID descriptor/endpoint with multiple reports vs multiple HID descriptor/endpoints each with a single report?

Tags: microcontroller, usb, bluetooth, software, hid

Consider the two following setups:

#### Setup A:

Single device with a single HID descriptor and endpoint pair, whose Report descriptor contains multiple Collections and Report IDs.

#### Setup B:

Single device with multiple HID descriptor/endpoint pairs, each having their own Collection and a single Report (no Report ID used).

#### Known tradeoffs:

- Setup B is more space efficient in terms of the report size, since there is no byte used for a Report ID.

### Question:

What other tradeoffs can I consider? Does using multiple endpoints slow down overall communication?

Answer (score 1):

They serve different purposes

Multiple HID descriptor allows listing different devices, like a mouse and a keyboard, custom within the same USB connection.

You could have for instance a device that lists a custom device with your own driver as well as a COM port directly supported by the system, allowing several communication methods.

Endpoints are really different communication endpoints.

Concerning speeds, the limit will be the communication speed of the USB device and USB protocol. Endpoints are a few bytes of data sent when the device is connected, nothing really that will make any differences.

Comment: Do you know if with a single endpoint w/ multiple reports the different reports are all contained in each USB transaction? (so multiple reports per USB packet)